# Question about recursive algorithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recursive-algorithms

I have following problem:

> $$f(n)=\frac{1}{1^2+1}+\frac{2}{2^2+1}+\frac{3}{3^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$
>
> - Write recursive algorithm for $f(n)$
> - Prove that recursive algorithm is correct
> - Count steps

I don't know where to start, any hints about how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. I need most help on first and third question, It probably will be easy to prove the equation by induction as the second question asks. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+\frac{n}{n^2+1}, \quad f(1) = \frac12$$

Comment: That would be correct but how would I continue to prove it by mathematical induction

Comment: Try it - as you mentioned, it is not hard at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean writing an algorithm that calculates $ f(n) $?

```
float sum(n) {
if (n==0) return 0
else return sum(n-1) + n/(n*n + 1)
}
```

Comment: No I need recursive mathematical formula, which then can be proved by mathematical induction